# Must employer give 2 weeks work if work is shift work and employee gave notice

Tags: employment, canada, british-columbia, ontario

I work for a company that periodically asks employees what their availability is and assigns shifts based on that. The calendar with the shift information is about at it's end and a new one hasn't come out yet. I told my manager I'm thinking of quitting. She said she might not assign me more shifts.

Legally, must the company continue to give me the same amount of work for the next 2 weeks?